# Is Retardation and Deceleration the same thing?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, definition

Does, Deceleration always have to be Retardation? Or, can there be Deceleration without Retardation.

Comment: I never thought of them to be two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Yep they are synonyms for the same thing - 'negative acceleration'.

Answer (score 0):

**Deceleration** and **retardation** used more-or-less interchangably to mean **negative acceleration**.

Because the velocity is a vector, this has a counter-intuitive meaning: Consider throwing a ball in the air. The ball has some positive (up-directed) initial velocity, and a negative (downword) acceleration $-g$ (which is roughly $-9.8m/s^2$). So the ball is "decelerating": The ball's velocity starts at some positive value, goes down and down until it reaches zero velocity (at that point, the ball is at it's peak height) and since the negative acceleration continues, the ball's velocity now becomes negative and becomes more and more negative over time (it falls faster and faster). So although the ball is still "decelerating" (has a negative acceleration), it is actually speeding up, just downwards!

Because of this counter-intuitive meaning, when talking physics and not some informal chat, it's usually better to say that there is "negative acceleration", instead of saying that there is either "deceleration" or "retardation".

Answer (score 0):

Retardation which is a word which is often used when the speed or velocity (used as synonyms in ordinary conversation) is decreasing but that can cause ambiguity when used in a scientific sense.

Suppose that a body is moving with a velocity $10\,\hat x\,\rm m/s $, (speed $5 \,\rm m/s$) and is subject to a retardation of $5\,\rm m/s^2$ which means an acceleration of $-5\,\hat x\,\rm\,m/s^2$.
For the first two seconds the speed decrease and it comes to a stop but beyond that time, even though it was called a retardation, the speed actually increases.

I therefore think that it is best to avoid using the word *retardation*.